# Assign data to an item in a list?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I've set up a list that shows all available fonts. The issue I am having is assigning the actual font "data" to the list item itself so that,  when clicked, it will apply that font to the textbox.

How would I go about doing this? 
(I'm entirely new to this)

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? You're more likely to get some assistance if you can demonstrate that you have at least made sole sort of attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to, in your case. But if I interpret your question correctly..

What you *can* do is something like this:

```
myTextBox.Font = New Font(myListBox.SelectedItem, myTextBox.Font.Size)
```

This way, you'll be able to assign the font to the textbox based on your listbox's selected item, provided the listbox item IS the name of the font.